# jQuery Selector for server side control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

What is the difference between `$('#<%=lblName.ClientID%>')` and `$("[id$=lblName]")`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`$('#<%=lblName.ClientID%>')` will find an element with the `id` attribute as supplied by the `ClientID` property in ASP.Net.

`$("[id$=lblName]")` will find an element with an `id` attribute that ends with `lblName`, for example `foo-lblName`.

Comment: for anyone that wants to choose one of them, if you have a page that uses a control page (ascx) more then one time - `$("[id$=lblName]")` will contain more then 1 element with an id ends with that name. so in this situation `$('#<%=lblName.ClientID%>')` will be a unique selector to the control

Answer (score 2):

`$('#<%=lblName.ClientID%>')` - # is the Id [selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) used by JQuery to identify the element with id.

`$("[id$=lblName]")` - [Will select all the elements with id attribute which ends](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) with lblName

Answer (score 1):

First one(`$('#<%=lblName.ClientID%>')`), id selector, will find an element by its ID. That is very fast as it will use native `document.getElementById`

Second one, [Attribute Ends With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), works in different way. In IE, for instance, it will get all elements and test ID of each element if it ends with provided value (or something similar). That is much slower. In newer browsers there is [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) which possibly will be used to find an element by that selector, but I'm not sure if it is supported by that functions (Well, [here](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/syntax/selectors/attribute.htm) it is defined like vailid css3 so suppose modern browsers will support ends with selector in querySelectorAll).

So, in conclusion, id selector should be faster in any case and much faster in case of old browsers. At the same time, ends with selector allows you to find an element without passing its client ID to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding what I came to know today, `$('#<%=lblName.ClientID%>')` will select only one element, however `$("[id$=lblName]")` will select more than one element, so if you have same id assigned to more than one element and if you would like to traverse all of them then first case will not work properly.