# webform not running script

Tags: javascript, webforms

I have a webform, with asp controls, with  I want to see if it's checked to display more informations (Checkbox1 is checked so --> div : yourDivClass show). but in my page It's not working
here is my code :

```html
<%@ Page Title="Form" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Form.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Form" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
    <head>
        <style>
.yourDivClass{
    display:none;}
        </style>
        <script language="text\javascript">
            $("#CheckBox1").change(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                    $(".yourDivClass").show();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>  
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <table>            
            <tr>
                  <td >Do you have...?</td>  
                <td class="hiddenText"> 
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    </td> 
            </tr>           
        </table> 
      </asp:panel>   
<div class="yourDivClass">Im Your div</div>    
    <table>
          <tr>  
                <td>  
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" ForeColor="#FF66FF" OnClick="Button1_Click" />  
                </td>  
                <td>  
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>  
                </td>  
            </tr> 
    </table>
</body>  
</html>
</asp:Content>
```

any Ideas please

Comment: Any console errors/logs?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I dont see anything in the console maybe I m not looking in the right place, could you please give me further informations ?

Comment: Google "Chrome dev tools console", "IE dev tools console" or "Firefox dev tools console"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is an asp control the ID of CheckBox1 is getting additional strings.
For client side manipulations add this:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

to your asp control.

You can look at this example:
[jQuery Selector for server side control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721615/jquery-selector-for-server-side-control)

or you can try to use this selector:

```
$("input[id$='_CheckBox1']")
```

look at this example which works:

```
<ul runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" id="DatesPickList" class="datesPickList">


$("#DatesPickList").css("background", "red");
```

Comment: I need to put ClientIDMode="Static" for all asp controls if I want to add other ones ?

Comment: I tried ClientIDMode.... not working but I ll try now the selector thanks

Comment: Now I have failed to load ressource: the server responded with status 404 , could you please give me your test code ?

Comment: I modified the checkbox lins  : <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/> (without changing all the code) but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is working :

```html
<%@ Page Title="Form" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Form.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Form" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   
    <!DOCTYPE html>  

<html>  
    <head>

        <script type="text\javascript">
      
             <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function ShowPanel1() {
                //Check if checkbox is checked or not
                if ($('#CheckBox1').is(':checked')) {
                    //Show the Panel
                    $('#Panel2').show();
                }
                else {
                    //Hide the Panel2
                    $('#Panel2').hide();
                }
            }


        </script>

    </head>
<body>  
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <table class="auto-style1">  
        
            <tr>
                  <td class="auto-style3">Do you have ... ?</td>  
                <td class="hiddenText"> 
                    <asp:CheckBox  ClientIDMode="Static" ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onchange="javascript:ShowPanel1()" />
                    </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr>  
                <td class="auto-style2"> </td>  
                <td class="auto-style4"> </td>  
                <td> </td>  
            </tr>  
          
        </table> 
      </asp:panel>
    <div>
        <br />
    </div>
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display: none">Test Panel</asp:Panel>
        <div>  
        </div>  
  
    <p>  
           
    </p>  
    <table>
          <tr>  
                <td class="auto-style2"> </td>  
                <td class="auto-style4">  
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" ForeColor="#FF66FF" OnClick="Button1_Click" />  
                </td>  
                <td>  
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>  
                </td>  
            </tr> 
    </table>
</body>  
</html>
</asp:Content>
```